# Gitlab CI / CD : Unauthorized when runner try to clone project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I try to use Gitlab CI / CD with GilLab Runner for the first time. GitLab is a self-hosted version.

I have a git project in GitLab. By default users must use SSH with private key to use git commands. 
But I would like to specify that access control is set to both : SSH and HTTPS.

For this project I create a simple `.gitlab-ci.yml` file (with a single test step) and a GitLab runner using the token specify by GitLab.

When I run the job, the following error occurs :

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.1.0 (de7731dd)
on BK_runner_Test3 hcVfxLhx
Using Shell executor...
Running on ns344345...
Fetching changes...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/hcVfxLhx/0/XXXXXXXXX/test/.git/
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@gitlab.xxxxxxxx.com/XXXXXXXX/test.git/': The requested URL returned error: 500
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Finally, in the Apache logs, I found a request with error 401 and 500.
So, I think, at that time, the job try to clone the project. So I try the following command :

```
git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@gitlab.xxxxxxxx.com/XXXXXXXX/test.git/
```

And the result is an error 401 !
Of course [MASKED] was replaced with the right token, used to declare tue runner.

So why this error 401 ? What did I miss in the configuration in order to authorize jobs using git commands ?

---

More information from log file `/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log`

```
Started GET "/XXXXXXXX/test.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack" for 111.222.333.444 at 2019-08-08 15:39:05 +0200
Processing by Projects::GitHttpController#info_refs as */*
Parameters: {"service"=>"git-upload-pack", "namespace_id"=>"XXXXXXXX", "project_id"=>"test.git"}
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 15ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms | Elasticsearch: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/XXXXXXXX/test.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack" for 111.222.333.444 at 2019-08-08 15:39:05 +0200
Processing by Projects::GitHttpController#info_refs as */*
Parameters: {"service"=>"git-upload-pack", "namespace_id"=>"XXXXXXXX", "project_id"=>"test.git"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms | Elasticsearch: 0.0ms)

JWT::DecodeError (Nil JSON web token):
```

Comment: The actual error the clone command reports is a 500. This means something is wrong with GitLab itself. Check `/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log` (assuming Omnibus installation method) for the 500 error. What is that error? It will help steer us toward the fix.

Comment: Log file confirms that it's a 401 error : `Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 15ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms | Elasticsearch: 0.0ms)`

Comment: But there is a message : `Nil JSON web token`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Git request is being authenticated/authorized correctly in GitLab Rails, but when it's passed over to GitLab Workhorse to actually send the data to the client, some authorization fails.

Check workhorse logs to see if there's more information. That will be in `/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/` by default in an Omnibus installation. I'm not exactly sure what would cause this but for some reason the header that authorizes workhorse isn't present.

Make sure your GitLab version is reasonably close to your runner version. I see you're running Runner 12.1 so GitLab should also be 12.1.

Comment: GitLab version is 12.1.4-ee. `/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/` exists but most recent log is older than my test. `{"level":"info","msg":"Starting","time":"2019-08-07T07:20:58+02:00","version":"gitlab-workhorse v8.7.0-20190805.223506"}
{"level":"info","msg":"keywatcher: starting process loop","time":"2019-08-07T07:20:58+02:00"}
{"address":"/var/opt/gitlab/redis/redis.socket","level":"info","msg":"redis: dialing","network":"unix","time":"2019-08-07T07:20:58+02:00"}`

Comment: Did you move log files elsewhere?

Comment: No, I didn't change anything about log files. I left the standard settings by default.